# Need NetSuite search formula to display employee time records by projects (in rows) and day of week (in columns)

Tags: sql, netsuite

I'm trying to create a NetSuite Time **search** that emulates the chart style display on an employee's weekly time record, with projects listed in rows and days of the week listed in columns, with totals by day and by project. The goal is to have a search auto filtered by "Last Week" that can be used with a drop down selector filter for employees. I know there are better ways, but this is a very specific demand from someone above who believes the NS time record is a "query" and wants it to act like one.

I'm good with NS searches but know almost next to nothing about coding. I tried some basic sum formulas using CASE WHEN but am having 2 issues:

1) Can't figure out how to get CASE WHEN to sort by the weekday output from DAY of the {date} and subsequently total the hours.

2) Not sure how to total hh:mm formatted time in searches, and can't figure out what the system name of the "Duration (Decimal)" field is.

Just need one line of a sum formula to total time data from one day of the week, and a way to solve the hh:mm issue and I am good to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE WHEN to_char({date}, 'D') LIKE 1 THEN {durationdecimal} ELSE 0 END

SUN = 1, MON = 2, etc.